# Controller & routes

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, controller, routes

According to the tutorial, it is possible to handle all the requests for static pages through application/controllers/pages.php

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/nav', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/aside_right', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/bottom', $data);
    }
}
```

This works for the "home"-page, but I don't seem to be able to call views/pages/about for example.

I tried to make a seperate controller for the about-page. It works, but it feels somewhat wrong.

application/controllers/about.php

```
class About extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/nav');
        $this->load->view('pages/about');
        $this->load->view('templates/aside_right');
        $this->load->view('templates/bottom');
    }
}
```

I also have issues with my htaccess file or routes file. With the About-controller written above, I can only get to the page by typing domain.com/index.php/about. I'd like it to be domain.com/about etc.

This is what my routes.php's like:

```
$route['about'] = 'about';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

My Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said, you don't need to use another controller for the `about` pages. Your problem is with your `routes.php`.

```
$route['about'] = 'about';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

In this way, it will search for a controller named "about" and it doesn't find the controller. If you erase the first line:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

It should work. In this case, as you request any page, for example `about` it will call `pages/view/about`, where `pages` is the controller, `view` is the function and `about` is the argument that is passed to the function (replacing the default `$page = home`).

I also spotted another error in your logic. You wrote

> This works for the "home"-page, but I don't seem to be able to call views/pages/about for example.

You don't have to call `view/pages/about`. You've to call `pages/view/about`. Remember that the syntax is always the same `Controller/Function/Variable1/Variable2/Variable3`. So, you should be able to see the `about` page with `http://yourdomain.com/index.php/pages/view/about` or only with `http://yourdomain.com/about` if you have the `$route['(:any)'] = pages/view/$1` rules in your `routes.php`.

Comment: Thank you, a lot of clarity now! Still got issues with the URL though, I can only reach it through domain.com/index.php/about/ and not domain.com/about or domain.com/pages/about

Comment: @estrar, then the error is in your `.htaccess`. Have a look here for a working `.htaccess`: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html